# Material Design Transparent ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I'd like to know if anyone knows how to make an activity with transparent action bar,
like the one you have in the new Google Play Store when you go to an app's page.

I don't care about the scrolling and turning from transparent into solid color background,
I just need the action bar transparent.

Answer (score 50):

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

This above will result exception on Lollipop devices. colorPrimary must be opaque.

Stylish your actionbar using style:

```
<style name="ThemeActionBar"
        parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@null</item>
</style>
```

And in your theme, just include:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

Comment: If you want tint (i.e. translucency), instead of `@null` as background (which results in full transparency), use color with alpha value like `#30000000`

Comment: on Marshmallow there is no no exception with  `<item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item> ` are you sure there was any issue on Lollipop ?

Comment: **Perfect Solution!** The transparent color throws an exception in **Lollipop devices.**  **_API 22 doesn't allow alpha channel._**

Answer (score 27):

You just need to put `<item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>` and set `windowActionBarOverlay` to true on your app theme
like this:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/my_text_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Final result should look like this:

[image: final result of code]

Comment: Great, It worked. But, as you can see here: https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10629709_805789872797492_6827913796269231038_n.jpg?oh=ac43335ed7c387f8c6ed10edfd1faa0f&oe=54B0A62D&__gda__=1420431431_2dfb271b8cb28aee5df2b805507d7e5e

There is a little shade of black at the top... can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801289/android-translucent-background-with-shadow

Answer (score 11):

1) Set `AppBarLayout` elevation property to `0dp`.

> app:elevation="0dp"

2) Set `Toolbar` background color to transparent.

> android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Whole xml will look like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        ......

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: It works for me if you remove the `android:background` attribute from the Toolbar and set `android:background="@color/transparent"` on the AppBarLayout.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

to styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/color_primary
    </item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
</style>

<style name="MainTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="elevation" tools:targetApi="lollipop">0dp</item>
    <item name="background">@color/semi_transparent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

to colors.xml:

```
<resources>
<color name="color_primary">#212121</color>
<color name="color_primary_dark">@android:color/black</color>
<color name="color_accent">#4285F4</color>
<color name="semi_transparent">#66000000</color>
</resources>
```

in AndriodManifest.xml select MainTheme: android:theme="@style/MainTheme">

Comment: what? which theme need set as theme?!

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);   
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 7):

**Transparent Actionbar**

*values/styles.xml:*

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/default_yellow</item>
</style>
```

*values-v21/styles.xml:*

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/bg_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/default_yellow</item>
</style>
```

use these themes in your *AndroidManifest.xml* to specify which activities will have a transparent or colored *ActionBar*

```
<activity
            android:name=".MyTransparentActionbarActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent"/>

    <activity
            android:name=".MyColoredActionbarActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"/>
```

Comment: In my manifest file I put android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" in the activity tag as shown and it would not work for me. Then I moved it inside the application tag (line 11 for me) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

There is also way to do it pragmatically.

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
mActionBar.setElevation(0);
```

Comment: It works. Add getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY); before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);