# Overlay the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I'm creating a gallery activity, and I want to overlay the action bar just like in the normal gallery app, similar to this:

[image]

In styles.xml, I created the theme:

```
<style
    name="GalleryTheme"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

And in the Android manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activities.Gallery"
        android:label="Gallery"
        android:theme="@style/GalleryTheme">
</activity>
```

However this didn't do anything at all. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post a picture or a screenshot of what you want to achieve? I don't think I have the same Gallery app

Comment: You want the action bar translucent with content showing beneath it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558705/material-design-transparent-actionbar

Comment: I added a photo of what I'm looking for

Comment: I think you would be able to do that using a `FrameLayout` and putting a `Toolbar` with a transparent background on top of your content