# Hamburger icon without ActionBar not with Transparent Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to have a Hamburger icon on my activity without the action bar. I have seen examples to do this with transparent action bar but i don't want it to be transparent one. I actually do want to add the action bar and if i click the hamburger icon it should show the Navigation Drawer. The layout is similar to Uber Android app. For reference i am also posting an image with red marked. Please help me to implement the same.[image]

Comment: Why do you need the icon without an action bar?

Comment: i want to implement a similar layout like uber

Comment: you need a transparent toolbar, which you can do by changing the color of toolbar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent action bar and status bar like Uber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950361/transparent-action-bar-and-status-bar-like-uber)

Comment: You have the answer here. Please check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add a view on top|left corner of root view and on click that view just open navigation drawer

```java
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

if (!drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
} else {
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot for the solution.

Comment: this is a proper solution and not rotating

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1600"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

Uber has transparent actionBar or toolbar... you can achieve that by both ways

- Keeping your icon on the **transparent actionbar/toolbar** ... go through this link .. [Material Design Transparent ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558705/material-design-transparent-actionbar)
- Without using actionbar just placing the icon and opening the drawer at its click.. and **handling the rotating animation at click and then changing the hamburger icon to back button** at the animation end.. rotate anim like this at onClick of icon..