# Make transparent action bar without showing block shadow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am trying to achieve my action bar which comes with android studio,look like this [image].

I am trying to make the action bar transparent.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26452534/2756662) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374300/2756662) and lots of other things. I am a newbie in xml design and styling in android.

Here is my `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this with style file, try to to implement this in your java file.Put the following function in your activity in which you want this functionality. In `onCreate()` method before setting the content view of activity, call this method. It will work for API level 21 and above smoothly.

```
    public void makeActivityFullscreenTransparent(){


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Making notification bar transparent
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    }
```

Comment: I am looking for transparent action bar we will look later into notification bar .. thanks for helping

Comment: Above performs the same function, also if you want that action bar will disappear after few seconds above is the good code else you can remove first two lines of function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

[image]

**In style.xml :**

```
    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

**In activity :**

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

**In layout add this line to main element :**

> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: Sure :) and give result according to that

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode  thanks for your feedback, can you provide any details about your code?

Comment: may be you have chosen drawer theme for your activity then you need to add this style to that theme.